# working with Jquery dyanmic created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my simple script is append few elements through jquery .
what im trying to do is to add some ajax call for those created elements .
the issue is the event never work for those elements and i tried a lot of Jquery methods but all fail .

```
$("#currentbuild").append('<li class="cancelevent"></li>');
$('.cancelevent').bind("click",function(e) {
                        var eventid = $(this).attr('id');
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert(eventid);
                })
```

also i tried

```
$("#currentbuild").append('<li class="cancelevent"></li>');
$('.cancelevent').on("click",function(e) {
                        var eventid = $(this).attr('id');
                        e.preventDefault();
                        alert(eventid);
                })
```

but it never show up anything

Comment: need to delegate the .on, someone will give you the code for it soon, I gotta get off work

Answer (score 1):

You have it almost correct:

```
$("#currentbuild").append('<li class="cancelevent"></li>');
$('#currentbuild').on("click",".cancelevent",function(e) {
    var eventid = $(this).attr('id');
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(eventid);
});
```

This adds a `click` handler to `#currentbuild` (which is not dynamic and therefore always in the DOM).  However, instead of reacting to a click on itself, it only listens to clicks inside itself and only to elements that have a class of `cancelevent`.  And since you don't add a click handler to an element that may be added and/or removed dynamically, the handler will always be there.

EDIT:  As @tcovo points out in the comments below, your code should work as you posted it here.  I assume this is not exactly your code and the `append` happens dynamically as the result of another event handler (and not on page load as you suggest in your sample).

Also, `var eventid = $(this).attr('id');` wouldn't work in your example either, because there is no `id` attribute on the `<li>`... Another reason I assume this is not the exact code that is giving you trouble. :)

Comment: Steve is correct. Live used to be related to the entire document, but on's scope is limited specifically to the element you relate it to in your syntax. Where you are adding things into the DOM via manual insertion or AJAX, you have to back out to the outer-shell-container of the elements you are changing/inserting and use that as the basis of your selector.

Comment: Why do we need to delegate the event in this case? Shouldn't `$('.cancelevent')` exist in the DOM after `.append` is called?

Comment: @tcovo - I agree, in this exact case, it should work.  I assume that this is not the exact structure the OP is using and the append happens somehow dynamically somewhere else.